# Copy update module from Personal.xlsb workbook to activeworkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module in personal.xlsb workbook that has 15+ sub procedures with 20,000+ lines of code to upgrade my quoting spreadsheet to the latest version of changes.
when it is done running I need to copy over existing modules or delete modules and import the updated modules for the updates to run correctly.
any help is appreciated.

i have searched for answers but have not got anything to run.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

You can take inspiration from the code of the attached procedures, which are part of a module I created for an application. The object of the procedures of this module is precisely the manipulation of the modules (deletion, import, etc.). the procedures are part of an XLAM or XLSM workbook, and run for the Activeworkbook.

There is a lot of code, but you will probably find your happiness there.

There is a lot of code, but you will probably find your happiness there.

PS. The comments are in French.

Good luck

```
Sub importe_tout_modules_depuis_sauve()
'importe et remplace les modules depuis le dossier de sauvegarde
    
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
'*Appel recherche et active si non, si non install
If Not ReferenceActive("C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB", ThisWorkbook) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
End If

'*determine la variable "Nom de fichier" utilisée dans le calcul du chemin des fichiers modules
source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), "_", "")

'redefinit Source si classeur de cycle, ou ExamProcedure, ou Analyse_Ventes ou achats
If InStr(1, source, "Cycles01") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycles01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "Cycle") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycle_B01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "ExamenP") > 0 Then
    source = "Examen_Procedures_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesVentes0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_Ventes_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesTVAREC0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_TVA_REC_01"
Else
'supprime les espaces pour le nom des modules VBA
    source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), " ", "")
End If

'test si le dossier des sources vba existe
'*le chemin des modules à importer, bureau de l'utilisateur + la constante range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" + le nom de ce fichier sans l'extension + dossier CLs
With ActiveWorkbook
    repert = Range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" & source & "\"
End With
'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas
'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas
If Not Dir(repert, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString And Not Dir(repert & "Sauve\*.bas") <> vbNullString Then
    
    MsgBox "la mise à jour est impossible, le chemin des modules vba est inexistant", vbExclamation
    GoTo exit_
End If

supprime_tous_les_modules                         'supprime tous les modules du classeur

Import_Module_depuis_save                         'importe les modules e type 1  bas
Import_Cls_Wb_sh_depuis_cls                       'importe les modules e type 1  bas
Import_Frm_depuis_frm
Ren_Mod_End_1                                     'renomme les modules importés en doublon
'renomme_modules1
exit_:
End Sub

Sub Maj_Modules_Developpement_ext()               'Optional shdw As Boolean)
'importe les modules depuis le dossier de développement
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
'*Appel recherche et active si non, si non install
If Not ReferenceActive("C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB", ThisWorkbook) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
End If
Maj_Module_From_New
Maj_frm_from_new
'renomme_modules1
End Sub

Sub Import_Module_depuis_save(Optional shdw As Boolean)
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
'        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
'        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim StartLine As Long
Dim NumLines As Long
'Dim ProcName As String
Dim repert As String
Dim Module As Variant
Dim nom_module As String
Dim fichier As String
Dim module_import As Variant
'*definition au niveau procédure des variable de type optionnal supprimées en tant que paramètre
'Dim nom_projet As String
    
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

'*determine la variable "Nom de fichier" utilisée dans le calcul du chemin des fichiers modules
source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), "_", "")

'redefinit Source si classeur de cycle, ou ExamProcedure, ou Analyse_Ventes ou achats
If InStr(1, source, "Cycles01") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycles01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "Cycle") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycle_B01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "ExamenP") > 0 Then
    source = "Examen_Procedures_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesVentes0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_Ventes_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesTVAREC0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_TVA_REC_01"
Else
    source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), " ", "")
End If
'*Définit le classeur de destination (qui doit être préalablement ouvert).
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'    '*Nomme le projet du classeur actuel au soit fecxtools + nom du fichier sans l'extension  ex: Fecxtools_Cycle_X

'*le chemin des modules à importer, bureau de l'utilisateur + la constante range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" + le nom de ce fichier sans l'extension + dossier CLs
repert = Range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" & source & "\"

'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas
'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas
If Not Dir(repert, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "le dossier n'existe pas", vbExclamation
    GoTo exit_
End If

'*nb_module = Application.VBE.VBProjects(nom_projet).VBComponents.Count
fichier = Dir(repert & "Sauve\*.bas")
While fichier <> ""
    Debug.Print fichier
    nom_module = (Left(fichier, InStrRev(fichier, ".") - 1))
    
'If Not (UCase(nom_module) = UCase(ControleProcedureActiveDEV)) Then
'importe tous les modules présents
    If VerifierExistenceModule(nom_module) = True Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(nom_module).Type = 1 Then
            
            Set Module = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(nom_module)
            ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove (Module)
            Set module_import = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & "Sauve\" & fichier)
            
'Debug.Print fichier
        End If
Else                                              ''If propose = True Then                ' en pause
'If MsgBox("voulez-vous importer ce nouveau module " & Chr(13) & nom_module, vbYesNo) = 6 Then
        Set module_import = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & "Sauve\" & fichier)
        Debug.Print fichier
'End If
'End If
    End If
    fichier = Dir
Wend
exit_:

End Sub

Sub Maj_Module_From_New()
'recupere et remplace les modules depuis
'C:\Users\phm\Desktop\DEV\BAS_New\A_New_Communs
    
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
'        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
'        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim StartLine As Long
Dim NumLines As Long
'Dim ProcName As String
Dim repert As String
Dim Module As Variant
Dim nom_module As String
Dim fichier As String
Dim module_import As Variant
'*definition au niveau procédure des variable de type optionnal supprimées en tant que paramètre
'Dim nom_projet As String
Dim propose As Boolean
    
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

repert = Range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\A_New_Communs\" '& "New\"
'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas
If Not Dir(repert, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "le dossier n'existe pas ou est vide", vbExclamation
    GoTo exit_
End If
'*demande si on doit proposer d'installer les nouveaux modules
If MsgBox("proposition de nx modules", vbYesNo) = 6 Then propose = True
'*nb_module = Application.VBE.VBProjects(nom_projet).VBComponents.Count
fichier = Dir(repert & "\*.bas")
While fichier <> ""
    nom_module = (Left(fichier, InStrRev(fichier, ".") - 1))
'Debug.Print nom_module
'If Left(nom_module, 5) = "A_Exp" Then Stop
'If Not (UCase(nom_module) = UCase(ControleProcedureActiveDEV)) Then
    If VerifierExistenceModule(nom_module) = True Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(nom_module).Type = 1 Then
            
'If Left(Fichier, 1) = "X" Then Stop
            Debug.Print fichier
            Set Module = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(nom_module)
            ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove (Module)
            Set module_import = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & fichier)
            
        End If
ElseIf propose = True Then                        ' en pause
        If MsgBox("voulez-vous importer ce nouveau module " & Chr(13) & nom_module, vbYesNo) = 6 Then
            Set module_import = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & "\" & fichier)
            Debug.Print fichier
        End If
    End If
'End If
'End If
    
'        'pour une procedure spécifique dans le module
'        ProcName = "NomProcedure"
'
'        With CodeMod
'            'VBProj.VBComponents("Module2")'
'            '.ProcName.Delete
'            StartLine = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
'            NumLines = .ProcCountLines(ProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
'            .DeleteLines StartLine:=StartLine, Count:=NumLines
'        End With
    fichier = Dir
Wend
exit_:
End Sub

'*************************************************************************************'
'*Importe le code des feuilles et workbook
'*
'*
'*
'*
'*************************************************************************************'
Sub Import_Cls_Wb_sh_depuis_cls(Optional shdw As Boolean)
'* importe les fichier BAS correspondant aux macors de feuilles ou workbook, depuis
'* le dossier
'* C:\Users\phm\Desktop\DEV\BAS_New\PMSYNTHESE\Cls
'*Nécessite d'activer la référence "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"
Dim wb     As Workbook
Dim oModule As CodeModule
Dim VBComp As VBComponent
Dim x      As Integer
Dim cible  As String
Dim source As String
Dim repert As String
Dim nom_projet As Variant
Dim nom_module As String
Dim fichier As String
    
'*determine la variable utilisée dans le calcul du chemin des fichiers modules
source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), "_", "")
'redefinit Source si classeur de cycle
'redefinit Source si classeur de cycle, ou ExamProcedure, ou Analyse_Ventes ou achats
If InStr(1, source, "Cycles01") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycles01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "Cycle") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycle_B01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "ExamenP") > 0 Then
    source = "Examen_Procedures_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesVentes0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_Ventes_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesTVAREC0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_TVA_REC_01"
Else
    source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), " ", "")
End If

'*Définit le classeur de destination (qui doit être préalablement ouvert).
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook                           'Workbooks("CibleThisWB.xlsx")
'    '*Nomme le projet du classeur actuel au soit fecxtools + nom du fichier sans l'extension  ex: Fecxtools_Cycle_X
'    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name = "fecxtools_" & Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), " ", "")
'    nom_projet = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name
'*le chemin des modules à importer, bureau de l'utilisateur + la constante range("Path_VBA") & "BAS_New\" + le nom de ce fichier sans l'extension + dossier CLs
repert = Range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" & source & "\" '& "\New"

'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas

If Not Dir(repert, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "le dossier n'existe pas", vbExclamation
    GoTo exit_
End If
'*nb_module = Application.VBE.VBProjects(nom_projet).VBComponents.Count
fichier = Dir(repert & "CLS\*.cls")
While fichier <> ""
'*Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Fichier)
    nom_module = (Left(fichier, InStrRev(fichier, ".") - 1))
'If Not (UCase(nom_module) = UCase(ControleProcedureActiveDEV)) Then
    If VerifierExistenceModule(nom_module) = True Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(nom_module).Type = 100 Then
'*défini le module à importer, et l'importe (en tant que module de classe)
            Set VBComp = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & "CLS\" & fichier)
'*Le renomme (pour le supprimer plus facilement ultérieurement, il va aller dans modules de classe
            cible = "Temp"
            
            VBComp.Name = cible
            Set oModule = VBComp.CodeModule
'*Transfère les données chargées dans le module de classe activeworkbook.
'*Attention les données existantes dans "activeworkbook" sont écrasées.
            With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(nom_module).CodeModule
                x = .CountOfLines
                .DeleteLines 1, x
                .InsertLines 1, oModule.Lines(1, oModule.CountOfLines)
            End With
'*Suppression du module ancien
            With wb.VBProject.VBComponents
                .Remove .Item(cible)
            End With
            Debug.Print fichier
        Else
            MsgBox "le module sheet ou activeworkbook " & Chr(13) & nom_module & Chr(13) & " ne peut être importé, si il n'existe pas au préalable", vbExclamation
'*ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("activeworkbook").CodeModule.AddFromFile (repert & "\" & fichier)
'*pour renommer un nodule CLS ****** activeworkbook_.[_CodeName] = "activeworkbook"
        End If
    End If
'End If
'*passe au fichier suivant
    fichier = Dir
Wend
exit_:
End Sub

Sub Import_Frm_depuis_frm(Optional shdw As Boolean)
'*Nécessite d'activer la référence "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"
'* importe les fichier BAS correspondant aux macors de feuilles ou workbook, depuis
'* le dossier
'* C:\Users\phm\Desktop\DEV\BAS_New\PMSYNTHESE\FRM
Dim wb     As Workbook
Dim VBComp As VBComponent
Dim cible  As String
Dim source As String
Dim repert As String
Dim nom_projet As Variant
Dim nom_module As String
Dim fichier As String
Dim propose As Boolean
    
'*determine la variable utilisée dans le calcul du chemin des fichiers modules
source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), "_", "")

'redefinit Source si classeur de cycle
'redefinit Source si classeur de cycle, ou ExamProcedure, ou Analyse_Ventes ou achats
If InStr(1, source, "Cycles01") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycles01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "Cycle") > 0 Then
    source = "Cycle_B01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "ExamenP") > 0 Then
    source = "Examen_Procedures_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesVentes0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_Ventes_01"
ElseIf InStr(1, source, "AnalysedesTVAREC0") > 0 Then
    source = "Analyse_des_TVA_REC_01"
Else
    source = Replace(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), " ", "")
End If

'*Définit le classeur de destination (qui doit être préalablement ouvert).
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook                           'Workbooks("CibleThisWB.xlsx")
'*le chemin des modules à importer, bureau de l'utilisateur + la constante range("Path_VBA") & "BAS_New\" + le nom de ce fichier sans l'extension + dossier Frm
repert = Range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" & source & "\" '& "New\"
'*demande si on doit proposer d'installer les nouveaux modules USERFORM

If Not Dir(repert, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "le dossier n'existe pas", vbExclamation
    GoTo exit_
End If

'If MsgBox("proposition de nx modules USEERFORM", vbYesNo) = 6 Then propose = True
'*Nomme le projet du classeur actuel au soit fecxtools + nom du fichier sans l'extension  ex: Fecxtools_Cycle_X

'*compte le nombre de modules
'*nb_module = Application.VBE.VBProjects(nom_projet).VBComponents.Count

fichier = Dir(repert & "Frm\*.frm")

While fichier <> ""
'*Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Fichier)
    Debug.Print fichier
    nom_module = (Left(fichier, InStrRev(fichier, ".") - 1))
    If Not (UCase(nom_module) = UCase(ControleProcedureActiveDEV)) Then
'            If VerifierExistenceModule(nom_module) = True Then
'                With wb.VBProject.VBComponents
'                    .Remove .Item(nom_module)
'                End With
        Set VBComp = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & "Frm\" & fichier)
'            ElseIf propose = True Then
'                If MsgBox("voulez-vous importer ce nouveau module " & Chr(13) & nom_module, vbYesNo) = 6 Then
    Else
        Set VBComp = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & "Frm\" & fichier)
        Debug.Print fichier
    End If
'End If
'End If
    fichier = Dir
Wend

exit_:
End Sub

Sub Maj_frm_from_new(Optional shdw As Boolean)
'*Nécessite d'activer la référence "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"
'* importe les fichier BAS correspondant aux macors de feuilles ou workbook, depuis
'* le dossier
'* C:\Users\phm\Desktop\DEV\BAS_New\PMSYNTHESE\FRM
Dim wb     As Workbook
Dim VBComp As VBComponent
Dim cible  As String
Dim source As String
Dim repert As String
Dim nom_projet As Variant
Dim nom_module As String
Dim fichier As String
Dim propose As Boolean
    
'*Définit le classeur de destination (qui doit être préalablement ouvert).
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook                           'Workbooks("CibleThisWB.xlsx")
'*le chemin des modules à importer, bureau de l'utilisateur + la constante range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\" + le nom de ce fichier sans l'extension + dossier Frm
repert = Range("Path_VBA").Value & "BAS_New\A_New_Communs\" '& "New\"
'*et vérifie qu'il existe
'*et crée un dossier de sauvegarde si il n'existe pas
If Not Dir(repert, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "le dossier n'existe pas ou est vide", vbExclamation
    GoTo exit_
End If

'If MsgBox("proposition de nx modules USEERFORM", vbYesNo) = 6 Then propose = True
'*Nomme le projet du classeur actuel au soit fecxtools + nom du fichier sans l'extension  ex: Fecxtools_Cycle_X

'*compte le nombre de modules
'*nb_module = Application.VBE.VBProjects(nom_projet).VBComponents.Count

fichier = Dir(repert & "\*.frm")

While fichier <> ""
'*Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Fichier)
    Debug.Print fichier
    nom_module = (Left(fichier, InStrRev(fichier, ".") - 1))
    If Not (UCase(nom_module) = UCase(ControleProcedureActiveDEV)) Then
        If VerifierExistenceModule(nom_module) = True Then
            With wb.VBProject.VBComponents
                .Remove .Item(nom_module)
            End With
            Set VBComp = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & fichier)
        ElseIf propose = True Then
            If MsgBox("voulez-vous importer ce nouveau module " & Chr(13) & nom_module, vbYesNo) = 6 Then
                
                If Left(fichier, 1) <> x Then
                    Set VBComp = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(repert & fichier)
                    Debug.Print fichier
                End If
                
            End If
        End If
    End If
    fichier = Dir
Wend

exit_:
End Sub

Sub renomme_modules1()
Dim nb_module As Integer
Dim nom_projet As String
Dim i      As Integer
Dim wb     As Workbook
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim New_name_Module As String
    
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
'*Nomme le projet du classeur actuel au soit fecxtools + nom du fichier sans l'extension  ex: Fecxtools_Cycle_X
'Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name = "fecxtools_" & Replace(Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1), " ", "")

nb_module = VBProj.VBComponents.Count

'nom_projet = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name
'nb_module = ActiveWorkbook.VBE.VBProjects(nom_projet).VBComponents.Count
For i = nb_module To 1 Step -1
'*si le module est un module  standard (type 1)
    Debug.Print VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name
    If VBProj.VBComponents(i).Type = 1 Then
        If Right(VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name, 1) = "1" Then
            VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBProj.VBComponents(Left(VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name, Len(VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name) - 1))
'*supprime le dernier 1
'New_name_Module = Left(VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name, _
'Len(VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name) - 1)
'VBProj.VBComponents(i).Name = New_name_Module
            
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub

Sub Ren_Mod_End_1()
    
Dim VBComp As Object
Dim VBComps As Object
    
Set VBComps = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

For Each VBComp In VBComps
'MsgBox VBComp.Name & "=" & CompTypeToName(VBComp) & " = " & VBComp.Type
    If VBComp.Type = 1 Then
        If Right(VBComp.Name, 1) = "1" Then
'passe les composants feuille, dont le code name peut être terminé par 1
            If VBComp.Type <> 100 Then
                VBComp.Name = Left(VBComp.Name, Len(VBComp.Name) - 1)
            End If
        End If
        
    End If
Next VBComp

End Sub

Sub supprime_tous_les_modules()
    
Dim VBComp As Object
Dim VBComps As Object
    
Set VBComps = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

For Each VBComp In VBComps
    Select Case VBComp.Type
    Case 100
        With VBComp.CodeModule
            .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
        End With
    Case Else
        VBComps.Remove VBComp
    End Select
Next VBComp

exit_:
End Sub

'==============================================================
Sub ListModules()
    
Dim VBComp As VBComponent
Dim Msg As String
    
For Each VBComp In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    Msg = Msg & VBComp.Name & " Type: " & CompTypeToName(VBComp) & Chr(13)
Next VBComp
MsgBox Msg

End Sub

Function CompTypeToName(VBComp As VBComponent) As String
    
Select Case VBComp.Type
Case vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner
    CompTypeToName = "ActiveX Designer"
Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
    CompTypeToName = "Class Module"
Case vbext_ct_Document
    CompTypeToName = "Document"
Case vbext_ct_MSForm
    CompTypeToName = "MS Form"
Case vbext_ct_StdModule
    CompTypeToName = "Standard Module"
Case Else
End Select

End Function
```